# In stable rust, how to move the minimum value out of an array, dropping the other values?

Tags: arrays, rust, move-semantics, unsafe

I have a fixed-size array `[T; SIZE]` of values of a type T that is ordered (it implements `Ord`, but not necessarily `Clone` or `Default`). I would like to extract the smallest value of the array and drop all the others.

In nightly rust, I can use [`array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html) to achieve that, but if possible, I would like my code to compile on stable.

Currently, I'm using the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=64198434ca415485c0f5390f960b1215)):

```rust
// Don't call this function if T has a custom Drop implementation or invalid bit patterns 
unsafe fn get_min<T: Ord>(mut arr: [T; SIZE]) -> T {
    let (idx, _) = arr.iter().enumerate().min_by(|(_, x), (_, y)| x.cmp(y)).unwrap();
    unsafe { replace(&mut arr[idx],  MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()) }
}
```

Of course, I'm not very happy with that. Is there a solution that is safer, and maybe less verbose?

Comment: `MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()` is _never_ a correct thing to do. You're right not to be happy about this solution.

Comment: If your `T` implements `Drop`, this code will call `drop()` for uninitialized memory.

Comment: Yes, in the general case, it is undefined behavior. However, for values of T that don't have invalid bit patterns nor a custom Drop implementation, I think it's safe.

Comment: But  why isn't the array droped? if the method takes ownership of it right?

Comment: @lovasoa “However, for values of T that don't have invalid bit patterns nor a custom Drop implementation, I think it's safe.” No it's not. It's UB. The documentation explicitly mentions that `MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()` is UB even for trivial all-bit-patterns-valid non-drop Copy types like `i32`.

Comment: @Netwave It _is_ dropped, and that's the problem. We replaced one of the elements with unitialized memory, so we can't drop the element anymore.

Comment: @SvenMarnach aha, I overread and I was thinking the problem was something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In the 2021 edition of Rust (available in Rust 1.56 and up), the `into_iter()` method on an array returns an iterator over the owned items, so this becomes easy:

```
fn get_min<T: Ord>(arr: [T; SIZE]) -> T {
    arr.into_iter().min().unwrap()     // assuming SIZE > 0
}
```

In earlier versions of Rust, you can move the minimum to the beginning of the array, and then use a slice pattern to move the first element out of the array:

```
fn get_min<T: Ord>(mut arr: [T; SIZE]) -> T {
    for i in 1..SIZE {
        if arr[i] < arr[0] {
            arr.swap(0, i);
        }
    }
    let [min, ..] = arr;
    min
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=570e331691123c44a0e52c0414cc6df4))

Related questions:

- [How do I move values out of an array one at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34406251)

Answer (score -1):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn remove_smallest(numbers: &[u32]) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut numbers = numbers.to_vec();
    match numbers.iter().position_min() {
        None => numbers,
        Some(m) => {numbers.remove(m); numbers}
    }
}
```

Comment: This operates on a slice rather than a fixed-size array, it unnecessarily moves them to a heap-allocated vector, and it returns everything *except* for the minimum element.

Comment: oops, it seems I need to learn how to read again... lol